# how to get actor reference from map

Tags: scala, akka

So i have an actor which creates car actors, i add new cars into map,and i need to send message to definite car from map that it was destroyed, how can i do it?

```
    var cars = Map.empty[String, ActorRef]
   override def receive: Receive = {
   case CreateTank(id) =>
    val newTank = context.actorOf(Car.props(id,hp=100), s"tank-$id")
    cars = cars + (id -> newCar)
    sender() ! CarCreated(id)

   case CarDestroyed(id) =>
    val thisCar = cars.get(id)
    thisCar ! CarDestroyed
   }
```

Comment: can you add the code for supervisor actor and the error which you are getting.

Comment: instade of newCar in value of the map don't you think newTank should be the value because that's the actorRef for the new Car actor.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `get` on a `Map` returns an `Option`, so one approach is to call `foreach` on the result of the lookup:

```
var cars = Map.empty[String, ActorRef]

def receive = {
  case CreateCar(id) =>
    val newCar = context.actorOf(Car.props(id, hp=100), s"car-$id")
    cars = cars + (id -> newCar)
    sender() ! CarCreated(id)

  case CarDestroyed(id) =>
    cars.get(id).foreach(_ ! CarDestroyed)
}
```

When the above actor receives a `CarDestroyed` message, it sends a `CarDestroyed` message to the actor associated with the id, if such an actor exists.

Also, I took the liberty of adjusting the other case clause, since it appears that you're confusing the creation of a car with the creation of a tank.

Comment: don't  you think isDefined on option is better choice than foreach?

Comment: @RamanMishra no, `isDefined` is actually worse. Not `asDefined` per se, but `Option.get`, which is usually considered "code smell", and is better avoided.

Answer (score 0):

jeffrey is quite right .get on map gives the option in return you can do something like this:

```
var cars = Map.empty[String, ActorRef]
   override def receive: Receive = {
   case CreateTank(id) =>
    val newTank = context.actorOf(Car.props(id,hp=100), s"tank-$id")
    cars = cars + (id -> newCar) /* i think this should be newTank becaue 
it has the actor ref for the new Car actor */
    sender() ! TankCreated(id)

   case CarDestroyed(id) =>
    val thisCar = cars.get(id)
if(thisCar.isDefined)
    thisCar.get ! CarDestroyed
   }
```

Comment: @ifog sorry edited the answer should work now actully we need to do get on option to get the value of option. if we do .get blindly on the option it can cause None.get error so first we need to check if the option is defined or not